# How to prove that for every invertible matrix $U$ and $V$, null($A$)=null($UA$) and im(A)=im($AV$)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $U$ is $m\times m$, $A$ is $m\times n$ and $V$ is $n\times n$, how would you know that for every invertible matrix $U$ and $V$, null($A$)=null($UA$) and im($A$)=im($AV$)?

Personally I think null($A$)$\in$null($UA$) for $U^{-1}(UA)=A$ and null($UA$)$\in$ null($A$) for $U\cdot A=UA$, and the same applies for im$(A)$, is it correct, I feel like I missed something.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, you need to go back to definitions. Otherwise, what's to stop you from saying that $\operatorname{null}(A) = \operatorname{null}(AU)$ (which, by the way, is *not* necessarily true)?

For example, null$(A)$ means the set of all $x$ such that $Ax = 0$.  We then can state that
$$
x \in \operatorname{null}(UA) \iff\\
UAx = 0 \iff\\
U^{-1}(UAx) = 0 \iff\\
Ax = 0 \iff \\ 
x \in \operatorname{null}(A)
$$ 
We conclude that $\operatorname{null}(UA) = \operatorname{null}(A)$, since an object is in the first set if and only if it is also in the second.

You can make a similar proof of the second statement.

Comment: Thanks for the expanation, cool id btw

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks.